# Android custom composite view save and restore state not working

Tags: android, state, android-custom-view, custom-view, onrestoreinstancestate

Solved...

I have a composite view that contains some other controls.  I am trying to override save `onSaveInstanceState` and `onRestoreInstanceState`, but am getting a strange result.

The `Parcelable state` argument to `onRestoreInstanceState` is not of my custom sub-class of `BaseSavedState`, `SavedState` and always seem to be `BaseSavedState.EMPTY_STATE`.  (Look for the *"always fails"* code comment below...

It seems that the problem is likely with the save portion, as the `SavedState.writeToParcel` is not being called after `onSaveInstanceState enters.`  Almost as if whoever is calling `onSaveInstanceState` is throwing the result away before persisting it to the `Parcel`.

If it makes a difference, this view is hosted inside a fragment.

Any ideas?

**Here is my class definition:**

```
public class AddressInput extends FrameLayout
```

**Here is my `onSaveInstanceState` and `onRestoreInstanceState` pair:**

```
@Override
protected Parcelable onSaveInstanceState()
{
    // Return saved state
    Parcelable superState = super.onSaveInstanceState();
    return new AddressInput.SavedState( superState, mCurrentLookUp );
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState( Parcelable state )
{
    // **** (state == BaseSavedState.EMPTY_STATE) is also always true 

    // Cast state to saved state
    if ( state instance of AddressInput.SavedState )     // **** <---  always fails
    {
        AddressInput.SavedState restoreState = (AddressInput.SavedState)state;

        // Call super with its portion
        super.onRestoreInstanceState( restoreState.getSuperState() );

        // Get current lookup
        mCurrentLookUp = restoreState.getCurrentLookup();
    }
    else
        // Just send to super
        super.onRestoreInstanceState( state );
}
```

**Here's my custom `BaseSavedState` sub-class (inner class of `AddressInput`) :**

```
public static class SavedState extends BaseSavedState
{
    private String mCurrentLookup;

    public SavedState(Parcelable superState, String currentLookup)
    {
        super(superState);
        mCurrentLookup = currentLookup;
    }

    private SavedState(Parcel in)
    {
        super(in);
        this.mCurrentLookup = in.readString();
    }

    public String getCurrentLookup()
    {
        return mCurrentLookup;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags)
    {
        super.writeToParcel(out, flags);
        out.writeString( this.mCurrentLookup );
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<SavedState> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<SavedState>()
    {
        public AddressInput.SavedState createFromParcel(Parcel in)
        {
            return new AddressInput.SavedState(in);
        }

        public AddressInput.SavedState[] newArray(int size) {
            return new AddressInput.SavedState[size];
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: In case it matters, since both `onSaveInstanceState` and `onRestoreInstanceState` ARE definitely being called, the view DOES have an `id` assigned to it in the fragment layout.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Figured it out...  My custom view had the same ID for its `FrameLayout` as was being used for the specific instance of the custom view.  The state was being properly saved by the instance and then overwritten (cleared) by the `FrameLayout` which had no state to persist.

I also changed its base-class to a `RelativeView` which made more sense.

In custom view's XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/addressInput"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_edit">
```

And the instance usage:

```
    <com.myStuff.AddressInput
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/addressInput"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            app:addressMode="Domestic"
            app:showSelect="true"
            app:showClear="true" />
```

Changed to: (@+id/addressInput -> @+id/shippingAddress)

```
    <com.myStuff.AddressInput
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/shippingAddress"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            app:addressMode="Domestic"
            app:showSelect="true"
            app:showClear="true" />
```

Makes you wish there was some scoping for IDs to prevent this kind of thing.  Why should you have to know about a custom view's internals to make sure you avoid ID conflict?

Answer (score 2):

It's glad to see you solved the problem.

For your question about custom composit view, I think an improvement could be made to the custom view's XML file:

use the "merge" tag, rather than any actual layout tag (for example: RelativeLayout) as the root element.

This will prevent the view redundancy, as described in [this blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/03/android-layout-tricks-3-optimize-by.html). Also you don't need to assign any id to the custom view, so the id conflict can be avoided.

Sorry I don't have enough reputation to add a comment, so I write another post.